# Filter nested model collections in to_json in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, json

I have two models:

```
class Calendar < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :events
end

class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :calendar
end
```

I need to output all calendars with nested events as json and I can do it like so:

```
Calendar.all.to_json(:include => :events)
```

But I also need to filter events, for example:

```
where(:name => 'bla')
```

How would I do that? So far my solution is manually convert each calendar to hash, filter events and convert them to hash as well, then append events to calendar hash and convert to_json at the end. But I'm hoping there is a nicer approach.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
Calendar.includes(:events).where('events.name' => 'bla').to_json(:include => :events)
```

Comment: Update: simplified my answer. You don't need `all` here it seems.