# Filtering nested model collections in to_json include in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, postgresql

To start out I have already looked at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12633546/filter-nested-model-collections-in-to-json-in-rails) and [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41296609/include-nested-objects-relations-with-filter-in-rails-json-response).

I have a piece of code that has a couple different postgres calls, and then appends on another model collection named Category within our response. I want to filter out certain pieces of response depending on a search param passed in by the json. My current code is here:

```
   def clues
   ....
    clues = clues.where("category_id = ?", params[:category]) if params[:category].present?
    offset = params[:offset].present? ? params[:offset] : 0
    @result = clues.limit(100).offset(offset)

    respond_to do |format|
      if(!params[:category_keyword])
        format.json { render :json => @result.to_json(:include => :category) }
      else 
        format.json { render :json => @result.to_json(:include => Category.where("title LIKE ?", '%' + params[:category_keyword] + '%')) }
      end
    end
  end
```

Right now, the end if statement in the respond_to do is broken, as I don't think my :include for the else statement is in a correct format to filter out, as it just doesn't append the nested model to my json response. What is the best way to filter out these nested calls?

Comment: Jsut a small hint, you can reduce the second line to `offset = params[:offset].presence || 0`

Comment: Is `Clues` your model? Plural? It should be singular.